# Explain batch command please

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I want to create a folder with the name of the current date and time.
After searching a lot i found this which actually works.

Can someone explain what these batch commands do?

```
set timestamp=%DATE:/=-%@%TIME::=-%
set timestamp=%timestamp: =%
mkdir "%timestamp%"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set timestamp=%DATE:/=-%@%TIME::=-%
```

That's a string replacement.

1st:

**%DATE:/=-%** Replaces "/" character to "-" character in the DATE variable

(See: **Echo %DATE%** on your console)

2nd:

Adds the "@" character to the string after the DATE var and before the TIME var.

3rd:

**%TIME::=-%** Replaces ":" character to "-" character.

(See: **Echo %Time%** on your console)

```
set timestamp=%timestamp: =%
```

Next in that replacement replaces itself spaces to any characarter (so deletes spaces), but really any space is given so is not necessary in your example code.

You can learn more about Variable string replacement here: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html

Also you can simplify your code 'cause no need to setting the value first:

```
mkdir "%DATE:/=-%@%TIME::=-%"
```

Comment: great answer Elektro. thanks! can you vote my question ? it's really hard to find this on internet and maybe it will help others too. i need some reputation too to vote your answer, because i am kinda new here

Comment: Sorry to bother. I am not sure i can contact you on private on this website, and it doesn't seem to allow me to post another question, it sais "This post does not meet our quality standards." But i have one more question: **I am making a batch file that starts other batch files simultaneously.
I am using this code to set the time variable which i need in all batch files.
If i use the same syntax in every batch file, i will get different outputs. 
So how do i make this variable universal for all the files, do i have to use vb script?

    set timestamp=%DATE:/=-%@%TIME::=-% **bold**

Comment: um never mind. i just figured it out. setting the timestamp in the main batch file will make the variable universal and usable in all other batch files it opens

Comment: Also you can use SETX to set an enviroment variable in your system (Like "%TEMP%" var).

Comment: edit: it doesn't work i was mistaken. i just tested it with a simple batch code "cd %timestamp%" and the timestamps differ in each batch. i will try setx. hope it works

Comment: can you give me an email or IM to make the conversation a bit more smooth please? if you don't mind of course. i have some questions, and more to come. i am working on a self made bigger project and i get some troubles with every step i make. i promise i won't bother too much :)

Comment: the problem with setx is that i think it requires more privileges and might interfere with uac settings, which i don't want. i want to keep it simple and usable without administrator rights. So i was wondering if i can somehow make a variable (actually a constant) with the value of the timestamp at the moment of creation when i execute the main batch file which runs the other files. do i have to use call command?

Comment: ok i tried setx : setx timestamp "timestamp=%DATE:/=-%@%TIME::=-%" it creates the environment variable without admin rights or uac prompts but as the help itself says "Setx writes variables to the master environment in the registry. Variables set with setx variables are available in future command windows only, not in the current command window.", i can't make windows start in another session with the updated timestamp. Any ideas?

Comment: This line **set timestamp=%timestamp: =%** is necessary when using 12 hour time as a space is part of the time string before noon.  It can be left in for 24 hour time without breaking anything.

Answer (score 5):

Insert echo statements between the lines and you can see what the value of timestamp is

```
set timestamp=%DATE:/=-%@%TIME::=-%
echo %timestamp%
set timestamp=%timestamp: =%
echo %timestamp%
mkdir "%timestamp%"
```

Basically, the code is just removing the forward slash from the date and the colon from time since those are not valid directory names replacing them with hypens.

Read set /? Environment variable substitution  to get a better idea.